# Add another image programmatically and choose position

Tags: java, android

I got to add an image programmatically, but, I tried to just copy and paste the same code, but with different image-file. That did not work, instead it just chose the last image i "added". 
This is my code for adding one image:

```
String flag = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE");
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(flag, "drawable", getPackageName());

    LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    setContentView(linearLayout);
```

This is my "copy and paste":

```
String pic = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGECITY");
    int id1 = getResources().getIdentifier(pic, "drawable", getPackageName());

    LinearLayout linearLayout1= new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
    imageView1.setImageResource(id1);
    imageView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayout1.addView(imageView1);
    setContentView(linearLayout1);
```

Can anyone help me solve adding another image en position it at the bottom?

Comment: obviously you should get rid of `linearLayout1` and add image view to `linearLayout` and do not use second `setContentView`... obviously it doesn't make sens to store data in UI so it would be better to use ListView/RecyclerView

Comment: You are right, I'm not too good at this, just began with android and images programmatically, did not understand so much about linearlayout. But it works now, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

By Selvin's help, I removed:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout1= new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

And changed the variables with linearLayout1 to just linearLayout.